# Android ViewPager and loading images from web

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager

I need to make small app that will work like picture gallery: I should use view pager and when user swipe left or right, app should load image from url. I have an array with urls and it should start loading particular image when user swipe to new page (it should not load all images on the start). For example, if I'm on first page, I should see the first image from url (index 0 in array). When I swipe to second page, app should start loading image from index 1, and when if finish loading, it should appear on the screen. I made view pager working with images from resources, but I can't do it with remote images.

I should not use any existing libraries, codes or something like that. Here is my code so far:
Main activity:

```
    urls = new int[] {
            R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3, R.drawable.i4, R.drawable.i5

    };
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, urls);        
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my View adapter:

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] urls) {
    this.context = context;
    this.urls = urls;
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);
    // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
    imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imgflag.setImageResource(urls[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}
```

layout.viewpager_item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10dp" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="1dp" />
```

Any advices?

Comment: I have an example code for that,but I am at work now... If question wont answered,I will help you about that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ImageLoader like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso.with(context).load(urls[position]).into(imgflag);
```

Or:

```
public class AsynImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    public String url;
    public ImageView img ;

    public AsynImageLoader(ImageView img,String url){
        this.url = url;
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection connection;
            if (url.startsWith("https://")) {
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            } else {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            }
            connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if(img!=null){
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in your adapter you write:

```
AsynImageLoader task = new AsynImageLoader(imgflag,urls[position]);
task.execute();
```

Comment: I should not use any existing libraries. Only stuff from ADK

Comment: I tried your code and it compiles and builds, but not working - images are not loaded into image view. I put task.execute() just before ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView); in adapter.

Comment: Try a debug and see if there is an exception in the method doInBackground()

Comment: I just fixed it. img.setImageBitmap(image) should be inside protected void onPostExecute(Void result) method instead of doInBackground. Thank you!